# Is there anyway to log all system calls with DTrace?

Tags: monitoring, auditd, dtrace

I installed DTrace on Ubuntu by the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install systemtap-sdt-dev
```

Is there anyway to log all system calls with DTrace (it is possible by auditd but it crashes after 20 minutes)?

Comment: log all calls? why would you want to do this, this is an enormous amount of data on any active system.

Comment: @Sven for a sandbox